# How to send non letters with smtpib?

Tags: python, smtplib

I have a problem. I am trying to send myself a letter from python using smtplib, but when I try sending myself message with a : character, it sends me an empty message. What am I doing wrong? My code

```
import smtplib

passfile = open("gmpnlog.txt","r")
fromaddr = "gmailuser@gmail.com"
toaddr = "gmailuser@gmail.com"
msg = "Hello From Python:)"
username = "gmailuser@gmail.com"
password = str(passfile.read())
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com","587")
server.starttls()
server.login(username, password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, msg)
server.quit()
passfile.close()
```

My password is stored in another .txt file.

Comment: You might need to format the message in HTML encoding. The function `urllib.urlencode()` does this in Python 2, and `urllib.parse.urlencode()` does it in Python 3.

Comment: Actually, it does not, gives a type error.

Comment: My bad, `urllib.urlencode()` won't work. You want to use `urllib.quote()` instead, or `urllib.parse.quote()` in Python 3. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries, I still appreciate your help. You were the only one who heped at all!